# Elastic search throwing lot of errors

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch:

```
"version" : {
"number" : "6.8.6",
"build_flavor" : "default",
"build_type" : "rpm",
"build_hash" : "3d9f765",
"build_date" : "2019-12-13T17:11:52.013738Z",
"build_snapshot" : false,
"lucene_version" : "7.7.2",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
```

My magento version is 2.3.3. Configured Elastic Search 6+ to search catalog. But this is throwing lot of this error in my `/var/report` folder. Any idea what to do?

```
{ 
   "0":{ 
      "error":{ 
         "root_cause":{ 
            "type":"query_shard_exception",
            "reason":"failed to create query":{ 
               "bool":{ 
                  "must":{ 
                     "term":{ 
                        "category_ids":{ 
                           "value":"144",
                           "boost":1.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "terms":{ 
                        "visibility":"3",
                        "4"                        "boost":1.0
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "term":{ 
                        "manufacturer":{ 
                           "value":"Pioneer",
                           "boost":1.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "term":{ 
                        "color":{ 
                           "value":"Ebony",
                           "boost":1.0
                        }
                     }
                  }                  "should":{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "_search":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":2.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "name":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":4.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "sku":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":5.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "custom_weight":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":5.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "popular":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":6.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "speaker_special_features_value":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":6.0
                        }
                     }
                  }                  "adjust_pure_negative":true,
                  "minimum_should_match":"1",
                  "boost":1.0
               }               n
            }            ","            index_uuid            ":"            HCjB6lOjQfugdFIug3sXXA            ","            index            ":"            2727_product_1_v5            "},"            type            ":"            search_phase_execution_exception            ","            reason            ":"            all shards failed            ","            phase            ":"            query            ","            grouped            ":true,"            failed_shards            ":{"            shard            ":0,"            index            ":"            2727_product_1_v5            ","            node            ":"            aKdJWbF9R4u-yue2AEAa7Q            ","            reason            ":{"            type            ":"            query_shard_exception            ","            reason            ":"            failed to create query:{ 
               "bool":{ 
                  "must":{ 
                     "term":{ 
                        "category_ids":{ 
                           "value":"144",
                           "boost":1.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "terms":{ 
                        "visibility":"3",
                        "4"                        "boost":1.0
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "term":{ 
                        "manufacturer":{ 
                           "value":"Pioneer",
                           "boost":1.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "term":{ 
                        "color":{ 
                           "value":"Ebony",
                           "boost":1.0
                        }
                     }
                  }                  "should":{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "_search":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":2.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "name":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":4.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "sku":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":5.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "custom_weight":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":5.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "popular":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":6.0
                        }
                     }
                  },
{ 
                     "match":{ 
                        "speaker_special_features_value":{ 
                           "query":"Vivitek",
                           "operator":"OR",
                           "prefix_length":0,
                           "max_expansions":50,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "lenient":false,
                           "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "boost":6.0
                        }
                     }
                  }                  "adjust_pure_negative":true,
                  "minimum_should_match":"1",
                  "boost":1.0
               }               n
            }            ","            index_uuid            ":"            HCjB6lOjQfugdFIug3sXXA            ","            index            ":"            2727_product_1_v5            ","            caused_by            ":{"            type            ":"            number_format_exception            ","            reason            ":"            For input string:"Pioneer"            "}}}}
```

Please help.

Comment: Please post some errors.

Comment: "error":{ 
         "root_cause":{ 
            "type":"query_shard_exception",

Comment: Ah, I see errors.

Comment: hey any solution on that?